# Sitecore MVP-Site Docker Error

Tags: docker, container

I am following the readme for the MVP-Site: https://github.com/Sitecore/MVP-Site

I am getting the default site coming up and the cm site at https://cm.sc-mvp.localhost/sitecore/ but the https://mvp.sc-mvp.localhost/ site gives a 404, the mvp-rendering docker image is showing "exited (1)" in Docker Desktop and the error with  "docker logs -f mvp-rendering" is showing:

```
[2022-06-04T14:15:23.125031100Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: close C:\Users\dev1\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-06-04T14:15:23.124357300Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (edf8cafe) f6713b24-BackendAPI S<-C DockerDesktopElectron POST /usage
[2022-06-04T14:15:23.124357300Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][I] proxy >> GET /containers/fb3dcbb00285633536cdd0c6b6b6ca06ac71f39966c8068b2ef3a25ed879fc7c/json
[2022-06-04T14:15:23.126916200Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: close C:\Users\dev1\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-06-04T14:15:23.125031100Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (edf8cafe) f6713b24-BackendAPI S<-C DockerDesktopElectron bind: {"command":"containerStartClicked","count":1}
[2022-06-04T14:15:23.128042500Z][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Failed to fire hook: close C:\Users\dev1\AppData\Local\Docker\log\host\com.docker.backend.exe.log: file already closed
[2022-06-04T14:15:23.126057700Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (edf8cafe) f6713b24-BackendAPI S->C DockerDesktopElectron POST /usage (1.7004ms): OK
[2022-06-04T14:15:23.127079600Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][E] cannot rewrite volumes: &errors.errorString{s:"mount denied:\nthe source path \"\\\\Projects\\\\MVP-Site\\\\docker\\\\deploy\\\\mvp-rendering:C:\\\\deploy:rw\"\ntoo many colons"}
[2022-06-04T14:15:23.129651500Z][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] [common/pkg/proxy.(*containerInspectRewriter).ResponseRewrite(0xc0003380e0?, 0xc8?, 0xd639dd?, {0xe88070?, 0xc0000c0b80})
[2022-06-04T14:15:23.129701200Z][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] [ common/pkg/proxy/containerinspect.go:59 +0x2cd
```

Thoughs on what to try or debug next? I have been trying to get this solution up for a few days now.

Thanks,
~james

Answer (score 2):

The logs show the following issue

```
[2022-06-04T14:15:23.127079600Z][com.docker.proxy.exe][E] cannot rewrite volumes: &errors.errorString{s:"mount denied:\nthe source path \"\\\\Projects\\\\MVP-Site\\\\docker\\\\deploy\\\\mvp-rendering:C:\\\\deploy:rw\"\ntoo many colons"}
```

That means the volume syntax in docker-compose file contains extra colons, I guess this one

> deploy:rw

Check it out in the following **docker-compose.override.yml** file:

[image]